# i want create a first person game, help

Tags: animation, game-engine

i want create a first person game, but i dont have idea, i créate a home, a car for drifting,, i think in a town by game in family, play with animals with home, someone can explain and configure / or tell me how configure for bodies and cars with Logitech g29, sorry im argentino and i want play games with no kill...,i want play online ,entertenament me ,and others like my family,

I DOWNLOAD SOME .BLEND FILES AND I EDITE, IN ONE FIND A FPS WITH GUN AND I QUIT THE ARMS WEAPON , HAVE A MOUSE LOOK AND JUMP I INTENTED JOIN WITH A WOLF TO PLAY LIKE AN ANIMAL, BUT DONT MOVE, I EDIT A TURISMO CARRETERA CAR PUT A BBS RIMS AND FINE TIRES TO GO TO THE CIRCUIT OR DRIFT IN THE TOWN WHAT I HAVE IN IDEA, BUT THE PC DONT HAVE A VIDEO CARD SO DONT FUNCTION GOOD AND I DONT KNOW HOW MAKE A DRIFT CONFIG TO GAME WITH MY LOGITECH G29 WHAT WE SALE, I CONFIG A CUBE WITH THE OPTIONS TO FRONT MOVE AND BACK BUT IS LIKE A BUTTON, AND I DONT FIND HOW WORK LIKE SIMULATOR,(I LIKE LIVE FOR SPEED) AND THE DIRECTION DONT FIND HOW MEAKE FUNCTION AND THE TUTORIALS OF BLENDER IN YOUTUBE ARE IN PORTUGES OR ENGLISH, I SEARCH IN SPANISH ARGENTINA OR ESPAÑOL, BECOUSE I DONT FIND A GAME LIKE LIVE FOR SPEED I TRY TO MAKE A NEW GAME

PLEASE HELP ME
 :)

thanks

Manuel Lopez Toigo

[image]

Comment: In order to make better use of this site please limit your questions to concrete issues you are dealing with. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] section. Particularly [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) Broad questions with many steps asking how to go from beginner to master blender are not well suited for this site.

Comment: Please don't use all caps for text. Besides the fact that is [harder to read](http://uxmovement.com/content/all-caps-hard-for-users-to-read/) it is considered [yelling or shouting](https://newrepublic.com/article/117390/netiquette-capitalization-how-caps-became-code-yelling)... just rude... No hace falta gritar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can do it, but it's going to be a *lot* of work! Blender isn't the best tool for making the game itself, although it's indispensable for making stuff to go *in* the game.

Actually, making games with *anything* is going to be a lot of work, but it's easier with some tools than others. (:

I would check out the [Unreal Engine](https://unrealengine.com), which is made by Epic Games. It allows you to make games without writing any code, by hooking up blocks  together. (It still uses programming *concepts*, but that shouldn't be too hard to learn.) It also has a store where you can buy models and things for your game. Be warned, it's a very big download!

They have a bunch of video tutorials [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Videos/), and [answers.unrealengine.com](https://answers.unrealengine.com) is sort of like Stack Overflow for UE.

Also, **they require you to pay them 5%** (as of 2017-12-24) **of all the money you make from your game**, if you make any at all. (You can see their terms [here](https://unrealengine.com/eula).)

Comment: thanks, but i dont have money to pay :) some other program?

Comment: @Manu Unreal Engine is free. You pay after you start to earn money from the game. You can check also Unity.

Answer (score 0):

A tutorial series on creating games in the Blender Game Engine can be found in [BornCG](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLda3VoSoc_TSS7ht07sCt8zDCyAenOG6i)'s playlists on YouTube. This will go through the basics and provide you with some of the basic thoughts required about setting up a game.

Yes, you can make the game in the Blender Game Engine and you can make a basic game without any coding (only using the logic bricks).

@seaturtle has a good point, newer tools (than the Blender Game Engine) have better functionality and more flexibility. However, using the Blender Game Engine as a prototyping or a learning exercise could still be valuable. And you would still use Blender to model the stuff inside the game.

Comment: some tutorial in spanish?